# Saving NSUserDefault data and showing it in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save my data by NSUserDefaults and view it in table view. I have already set four texts data to an array (dataArray) so I can view it in the table view. but I couldn't load the data to the table view. So am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

```
-(IBAction)save{

NSUserDefaults *add1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[add1 setObject:txt1 forKey:@"txt1"];
[add1 setObject:txt2 forKey:@"txt2"];
[add1 setObject:txt3 forKey:@"txt3"];
[add1 setObject:txt4 forKey:@"txt4"];

[add1 synchronize]; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[prefs objectForKey:@"txt1"], [prefs objectForKey:@"txt2"], [prefs objectForKey:@"txt3"],[prefs objectForKey:@"txt4"] nil];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// Set up the number of rows
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [dataArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *string = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Why are you grabbing [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 4 times in a row?

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you for you post... I have four text field and I thought I need to call [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 4 times for each field. Please correct me if I am wrong, I am kind new to Xcode.

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi You can use just `add1` and then set each object on it, but you need to synchronize the userdefault to apply the changes...see my answer below.

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi You don't. NSUserDefaults is a singleton. http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons.html

Comment: I have edited my code I have an issue from viewDidLoad which is called object type 'id' is not a function or a function pointer.

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi You're missing a comma before the `nil`, then definitely gives you that warning because objectForKey returns an `id`, then you could do a casting, `(NSString *)[prefs objectForKey: @"txt1"];`, for each object.

Comment: I have posted the whole code in a document I hope this help to solve my problem. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vaXa1yo-p9xZPT2wJFGcM0LLksL3JAIxr4J58yPD4oI/edit

Comment: `cell.textLable.text` it's wrong, it's `textLabel`, but what's really your problem here?..If the problem is that you do not see the data in the table, probably you forgot to associate the dataSource and table delegate to `self` (or from the XIB)...or you are not entering in the <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>. of your Viewcontroller.h

Comment: @Mat There is no error in the code but when I write in the text filed I got long message   2012-05-05 13:58:10.985 SaveList[61038:f803] *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '<UITextField: 0x6a332a0; frame = (203 73; 97 31); text = 'DS'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a333d0>>' of class 'UITextField'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Comment: If txt1,txt2,etc are `UITextField`s, when you add the objects, if you want just add the text-string of the textfield, pass `txt1.text` ,not just `txt1`

Comment: @Mat it works now, But why when I click save button it doesn't do anything until I close the simulator and run the simulator again I can see the data that entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `[yourUserDefaultObject synchronize];` to save the state of the `NSUserDefaults`, but you don't really need to create 4 objects of NSUserDefaults, you can just create it one time and then call `setObject:forKey:` on the same instance and then `synchronize`.
Then just set `cell.textLabel.text=string;` to set the label of the cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` callback.

Comment: where should I call the [yourUserDefaultObject synchronize]; ? Also I have reduced the 'NSUserDefault' to one. Thanks Mat

Comment: You must call it after setting objects, so immediately after the last `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 1):

First syncronize nsuserdefaults and

You need to alloc the tableviewcell and assign the text to the text label

Add following code in your cellForRowAtindexpath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *string = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if(cell==nil)
{
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
  cell.textLabel.text=string;

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bhoomi I have got this message "proporty text lable not found on object of type "UITableView""

Comment: @Bhoomi you're missing the `return` statment.

Comment: @Luai see the updated answer.Replace UITableView by UITableViewCell

Comment: @Bhoomi now the error has gone thanks but it still not printing in the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Dude add following line because you need to add test somewhere in cell. So that can display on `tablviewcell.`  If possible than please first make array than save whole array in `NSUserDefaults` by that way you save your time and that's better way to do coding.

```
cell.textLabel.text=string;
```

**Edited>>>**

```
 UILabel *label;
label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 40)];

label.text = string;
```

// or

```
label.text = @"Hi I am here..";

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Thank you after I add the code I got this message "proporty textLable not found on object of type "UITableView""